# devise (No routes Matches [put] "/users/edit.user)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

ruby 2.3.3,
rails 5.1.6.1

I am trying to edit a user, after i click on the update, my app loads to this:

No route matches `[PUT] "/users/edit.user"`

```
# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :posts
  resources :projects
  resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]

  get 'welcome/index'

  root 'welcome#index'

  get '*path' => redirect('/')
end
```

Comment: Please post your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do

devise_for :users

resources :posts

resources :projects

resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]

get 'welcome/index'

root 'welcome#index'

get '*path' => redirect('/') end

Comment: @bottles can you please paste the code you use for generating the path (`/users/edit.user`)?

Comment: @bottles Add the form for user's edit

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a problem with your routes.rb file

check this guide -> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/routing.html#resources-on-the-web

from what I can tell you are not defining the routes pointing to your `UsersController` (`devise_for :users` doesn't do that, it defines completely other set of routes)

your routes.rb should look roughly like below:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users

  ...some other routes (like devise_for :users)

end
```

`resources :users` will define routes like `/users` for showing all user resource or `/users/:id/edit` for editing the user resource.

Now that you have those routes the will point to the UsersController class which should be defined in the users_controller.rb. In the controller you should define appropriate actions (like edit or update) that will update your user resource

I hope this is going to help solving your problem.

Comment: `devise_for :users` defines registrations#edit and update and sometimes it is enough for user updating.

Comment: hmm, from what I can tell it's not enough, check: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper%3Adevise_for it let's you update user password but from what I can tell you have to define your own routes and your own user controller to update user resource.

Comment: @vasilisa  devise_for :users defines registrations#edit and update and sometimes it is enough for user updating.                                                    yes,but i dont know why its giving me a problem. i first removed :registrable, so that i will be the only one to login. and i added back the :registerable. and even that, when i fill in the sign up form and click on the sign up button, i get the same error as the edit: no routes matches...